# How to set layout for each different modules in Zend Framework 2.2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to setup different Layout file for each different modules in Zend Framework 2.2.

For example I want to have different layout for 'Admin' and 'Application' module.

Answer (score 1):

[One approach by Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/module-specific-layouts-in-zf2/) uses something like this in `config/autloload.php`:

```
array(
    'module_layouts' => array(
        'Application' => 'layout/application',
        'ZfcUser' => 'layout/user',
    ),
);
```

An alternate [approach from Evan Coury](http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2) - the lead author for ZF2 module system, IIRC - uses this in the `Module.php` file for your module:

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
            // This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the MyModule namespace is dispatched.
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            $controller->layout('layout/alternativelayout');
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Hopefully, one of these will work for you.